# Is "git checkout -b branchName" the same as "git checkout --track origin/branchName"?

Tags: git, github

Is `git checkout -b branchName` the same as `git checkout --track origin/branchName`?   I'm trying to begin contributing to a remote branch from my local machine.  Are these commands equivalent?  If not, how do they differ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These options are a little different.

`git checkout -b BRANCHNAME` creates a new branch pointing to the same place as the *current* one and checks it out.  In other words, the new branch you've just created is generally equivalent to the old one (until you add more commmits).  The branch has no remote tracking branch associated with it.

With `-b`, it's also possible to specify a branch to base it off of, so you can use `git branch -b bug-1234 project-5678` to create `bug-1234` starting with `project-5678`.

`git checkout --track REMOTE/BRANCHNAME` creates a new branch (with the name `BRANCHNAME`) pointing to the same place as the *remote tracking branch you specified*.  The new branch has the specified remote tracking branch associated with it.  This implicitly uses `-b` under the hood if you don't specify it explicitly.

In general, if you want to just create a new branch off an existing one, use `-b`.  If you want to create a new branch that tracks a remote one, use `--track`.

Comment: This was super helpful.  I'm trying to very easily begin contributing to a remote branch from my local machine, so it appears the one with `--track` is what I'm after.  Great to know it uses `-b` under the hood.  Thank you.

Comment: @MickR: note, by the way, that the verb *track* is badly overused in Git. Branch name B "tracks" a "remote-tracking" name origin/B if origin/B is the *upstream* of branch name B. Meanwhile, a *remote-tracking name* like origin/B is your Git's way of remembering what B was over on `origin`, the last time your Git saw it. Independent of both of those meanings, a *tracked file* is a file that is in the index, so that an *untracked file* is any file that is *not* in the index. I like to try to avoid some of this confusing by avoiding the phrase "branch name B tracks ___", but what can one do? :-)

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you want to create a branch in your local working directory.  In that case you want `git checkout -b branchName`

**EDIT:**

Then, do your work and commit the work to your new branch (with "git commit").  You can make several commits to the new branch or just one.  Once you want it to be reviewed, do `git push -u origin`. Then follow the pull request process you have been given, if any.  Otherwise just contact the person you're working with and notify them that you pushed a branch and give the name.

Comment: So sorry for the ambiguity in my question - I've updated it with `I'm trying to begin contributing to a remote branch from my local machine.`.  Does this mean that the other option is what I need, since I want to push my changes directly to the remote branch?